# Snapkit 3.0 can't get correct frame after call layoutIfNeeded

Tags: swift3, snapkit

I updated **Xcode 8** and **SnapKit 3.0** to test auto layout. I can get frame correct after call `layoutIfNeeded` before i update to **SnapKit 3.0**. But i get `frame.origin.x` and `.y` both negative value now under **SnapKit 3.0**.

**example**:

```
        let signUpView = UIView()
        view.addSubview(signUpView)
        signUpView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.leading.equalTo(50)
            make.trailing.equalTo(-50)
            make.top.equalTo(topView.snp.bottom)
            make.height.equalTo(50)
        }
        // here frame is: {0,0,0,0}
        signUpView.layoutIfNeeded()

        // here frame is:
            (-137.5, -25.0, 275.0, 50.0)
            ▿ origin : (-137.5, -25.0)
              - x : -137.5
              - y : -25.0
            ▿ size : (275.0, 50.0)
              - width : 275.0
              - height : 50.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `layoutIfNeeded` on `view` rather than `signUpView` as it is the container that needs to do the layout pass.